# Como encontrar apenas os path distintos até o diretório específico?

Tags: linux, script

Quero encontrar somente diretórios distintos com o mesmo nome.

Se eu usar o `locate` para encontrar o path de um determinado diretório :

`locate` meu_diretorio :

```
/var/lib/meu_diretorio/arquivo1 
/var/lib/meu_diretorio/arquivo2
/var/lib/meu_diretorio/arquivo3
/var/lib/meu_diretorio/arquivo4
/var/lib/meu_diretorio/arquivo5
/tmp/eu_diretorio/arquivo2
/tmp/eu_diretorio/arquivo3
/tmp/eu_diretorio/arquivo4
```

Mas eu quero só a seguinte saída :

```
/var/lib/meu_diretorio/
/tmp/meu_diretorio/
```

Como encontrar apenas os path distintos até o diretório específico ?

Answer (score 0):

Digamos que eu saiba que existe um diretorio chamado `vcf` dentro do meu `/home`, mas não me lembro onde esta e queira encontra-lo:

```
$ find ~/ -type d -name "vcf"
```

Saída:

```
/home/sidon/temp/vcf
```

Voce pode usar `.ssh` para fazer um teste rápido:

```
$ find ~/ -type d -name ".ssh"
```

Saída:

```
/home/sidon/.ssh
/home/sidon/.x2go/.ssh
```